# How to do a task in background of c++ code without changing the runtime

Tags: c++

I was trying to create a bank system that has features for credit,deposit,transaction history etc. I wanted to add interest rate as well so I was thinking of adding it in after 10 seconds of delay but When I am using delay(like sleep()function). My whole program is delayed by 10 seconds. Is there a way for interest to be calculated in the background while my runtime of the code won't be affected?

Comment: Maybe just put the sleep call *right* before the print

Comment: Having multiple functions run at once is possible but tricky. Another approach could be to store the initial time, then any time later you need the total, subtract the current time minus initial time, and calculate how much interest has accrued during that time.

Comment: Your system is not multithreaded? All functions are being executed in sequence inside 1 thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just single task to be run then there exists [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), which allows to run a task (function call) in a separate thread.

As you need to delay this task then just use [std::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) or [std::sleep_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) to add extra delay within async call. `sleep_for` shall be used if you want to wait for certain amount of seconds, and `sleep_until` shall be used if you want to wait till some point in time, e.g. to sleep until `11:32:40` time is reached.

In code below you can see that `Doing Something 1` is run before start of async thread, then thread starts, which is waiting for 2 seconds, same time `Doing Something 2` is called. After that you may wish (if so) to wait for delayed task to be finished, for that you call `res.get()`, this blocks main thread till async thread is fully finished. Afterwards `Doing Something 3` is called.

If you don't do `res.get()` explicitly then async thread just finishes by itself at some point. Of if program is about to exit while async thread is still running, then program waits for this async thread to finish.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/jx394h5E8)

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int some_value = 123;
    auto const tb = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto Time = [&]{
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tb).count();
    };

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    std::cout << "Doing Something 1... at "
        << Time() << " sec" << std::endl;

    auto res = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        std::cout << "Doing Delayed Task... at "
            << Time() << " sec, value " << some_value << std::endl;
    });

    std::cout << "Doing Something 2... at "
        << Time() << " sec" << std::endl;

    res.get();

    std::cout << "Doing Something 3... at "
        << Time() << " sec" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Doing Something 1... at 0.000 sec
Doing Something 2... at 0.000 sec
Doing Delayed Task... at 2.001 sec, value 123
Doing Something 3... at 2.001 sec
```